# Getting Modal to onload when page opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, onload

Can someone help me, Im trying to get a Modal to load when the page does but having some serious issues about it.

```
<script>
   $('#overlay').modal('show');

setTimeout(function() {
    $('#overlay').modal('hide');
}, 5000);
</script>

</head>

<body>


<div class="modal fade" id="overlay">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Context here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what the serious issues are but... make sure that you wrap the show in document ready otherwise it may not work as the DOM won't have fully loaded

Comment: Use `$( document ).ready(function() {$('#overlay').modal('show');

setTimeout(function() {
    $('#overlay').modal('hide');
}, 5000); 
});`

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your call in document ready, to assure it will be called once the page fully loads, like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#overlay').modal('show');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#overlay').modal('hide');
    }, 5000);
  });
</script>

<body>
  <div class="modal fade" id="overlay">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Context here</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It works the way it should;yes. But then is completely messes with my whole webpage and turns my text different colors and the alignment are all off. Not sure why it does that.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

One .. You're not waiting until the `DOM` is fully loaded.  Use `$( document ).ready()` to achieve loading your script AFTER the `DOM` has loaded.

Two:  It's best practice to put your code AFTER the actual `DOM` elements, not before it.  That way the `DOM` is "almost" guaranteed to load before your script runs.

IE:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="overlay">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Context here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



   <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#overlay').modal('show');
       setTimeout(function() {
       $('#overlay').modal('hide');
       }, 5000);
     });
  </script>
```

**EDIT** 
I would use `.show()` and `.hide()`

```
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#overlay').show();
       setTimeout(function() {
       $('#overlay').hide();
       }, 5000);
     });
  </script>
```

Comment: I tried your way Zak, and nothing. Didn't want to work nothing changed. Any reason why?

Comment: I would suggest watching your `console` hit **F12** and refreshing the page to see what JS arrors are happening ..

Comment: This is what I got in the console   $(...).modal is not a function

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `.modal()`?    I would just use `.show()` and `.hide()`  --  See my edit above^^